# Proxy Basic Authentication return exception

Tags: c#

I tried to make proxy authentication with following code :

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(myurl);
System.Net.WebProxy proxy = new System.Net.WebProxy();
proxy.Address = new Uri("http://191.96.33.240");
proxy.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");

request.Proxy = proxy;
request.Method = "GET";

var webResponse = request.GetResponse();
var webStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
var responseReader = new StreamReader(webStream);
var response = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
Console.WriteLine("Response: " + response);
responseReader.Close();
```

But the program return me

```
Unhandled Exception: System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The URI is empty.
   at System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind)
   at System.Uri..ctor(String uriString)
   at System.Net.WebRequest.Create(String requestUriString)
```

Without proxy everything work as well.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote wrong username and it return me exception